# Is there a better approach to group the props and get the count of an object of arrays in javascript, less code but native approach

Tags: javascript, beginner

Could anyone help me with below logic implementation. I am new to Javascript and have been practicing advanced functions. The below code does the job but is there a better way to achieve the same? I want to make my code perfect.

I am grouping by location and then getting the sentiments count.

```
// Feedback
const sentiments = [
  { location: "France", sentiment: "dissatisfied" },
  { location: "France", sentiment: "happy" },
  { location: "France", sentiment: "happy" },
  { location: "Germany", sentiment: "happy" },
  { location: "France", sentiment: "sad" },
  { location: "Germany", sentiment: "sad" },
  { location: "Germany", sentiment: "happy" },
  { location: "Germany", sentiment: "happy" },
  { location: "Germany", sentiment: "sad" },
  { location: "Germany", sentiment: "dissatisfied" },
  { location: "Spain", sentiment: "dissatisfied" },
  { location: "Spain", sentiment: "happy" },
  { location: "Spain", sentiment: "happy" },
];


// Group by Sentiments
function GroupBySentiments(location, acc, cvalue) {
  let key = cvalue["sentiment"];
  // first time 0th index will be empty, so insert the sentiment
  if (acc[location][0] == undefined) {
    acc[location].push({ [key]: 1 });
  } else if (acc[location].findIndex((l) => l.hasOwnProperty(key)) == -1) {
    acc[location].push({ [key]: 1 });
  } else {
    let index = acc[location].findIndex((l) => l.hasOwnProperty(key));
    acc[location][index][key] += 1;
  }
  return acc;
}

//Group by location
result = sentiments.reduce((acc, sentiment) => {
  let key = sentiment["location"];
  if (!acc[key]) {
    acc[key] = [];
  }
  return GroupBySentiments(key, acc, sentiment);
}, {});
```

```
//OUTPUT
{
  France: [ { dissatisfied: 1 }, { happy: 2 }, { sad: 1 } ],
  Germany: [ { happy: 3 }, { sad: 2 }, { dissatisfied: 1 } ],
  Spain: [ { dissatisfied: 1 }, { happy: 2 } ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Output format

For each location, you have a list of objects with a single sentiment.

i.e.: `{ France: [ { dissatisfied: 1 }, { happy: 2 }, ... ] }`

To access how many are "happy" from France you would need to do something like

```
const happySentiment = results.France.find((sentiment) => sentiment.hasOwnProperty("happy"));
const happyCount = happySentiment ? happySentiment.happy : 0;
```

This is, imo, a lot of work just to find how many people are happy in France, at this point you might as well add +1 to dissatisfied for me.

Joke aside, if there is not a specific reason to work with that output format, why not generate something that is easier to handle?

i.e.: `{ France: { dissatisfied: 1, happy: 2 }}`

and thus to access the same result as before would be:

```
const happyCount = results.France.happy ?? 0;
```

## New Implementation

```js
const sentiments = [
  { location: "France", sentiment: "dissatisfied" },
  { location: "France", sentiment: "happy" },
  { location: "France", sentiment: "happy" },
  { location: "Germany", sentiment: "happy" },
  { location: "France", sentiment: "sad" },
  { location: "Germany", sentiment: "sad" },
  { location: "Germany", sentiment: "happy" },
  { location: "Germany", sentiment: "happy" },
  { location: "Germany", sentiment: "sad" },
  { location: "Germany", sentiment: "dissatisfied" },
  { location: "Spain", sentiment: "dissatisfied" },
  { location: "Spain", sentiment: "happy" },
  { location: "Spain", sentiment: "happy" },
];

const result = sentiments.reduce((acc, {location, sentiment}) => {
  const sentimentCounts = acc[location] ?? {};
  sentimentCounts[sentiment] = (sentimentCounts[sentiment] ?? 0) + 1;
  acc[location] = sentimentCounts;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I appreciate this, Very nice solution! many thanks

Comment: One option depending on your needs is just counting in the original array `(loc, sent) => sentiments.filter(s => s.location == loc && s.sentiment == sent).length`. Considered making this an answer, but it's more of a "for completeness" addition